Does the browser’s or router’s DNS cache take priority if they don’t match?
Almost all modern browsers and routers have DNS caches, which temporarily stores IP addresses of recently visited domains, essentially allowing faster access by avoiding repeated DNS lookups.
But what happens when they don’t match? If the one domain points to a different IP addresses on the browser and router. Who takes priority?

Is the browser’s cache used first?
Is the router’s cache used first?


Neither really "takes priority".  A browser-level DNS cache exists to avoid having to ask the DNS server at all.  If a DNS record is found in the browser's cache then the router (or other DNS server) won't come into play at all.
The same is also true of essentially every DNS server up the chain.  The server will answer with a result from its cache if it has one, and otherwise will query an upstream DNS server for the answer.  This goes on until either someone has the record cached or you reach an authoritative DNS server for a given domain.

There's no priority as such because they aren't used in parallel. These caches are connected "in series", that is, your router's DNS resolver is the upstream of the browser's resolver (just like your ISP's resolver is used as the upstream for your router's).
The browser is what initiates the query in the first place, so its resolver will check its internal cache first before going out to the network (because the local cache can give an answer faster than a network query).
And the point of having a cache is that if the cache has data, then the upstream is not queried at all, and therefore the cache wins by default. So if your browser already has an answer cached, then it just uses that – it doesn't query the router at all, and no comparison is done.
Doing otherwise (i.e. getting a result from cache and then querying upstream in order to check if they match) would basically negate the point of the browser having a cache in the first place, as it would take the same amount of time (perhaps slightly longer even) than if the browser didn't do any caching.

Yes, this does make a lot more sense. Maybe I just misinterpreted your answer, but I  don’t mean a router having an actual resolver (e.g. that queries mainstream resolver such as google,) but the same kind of cache as a browser/OS has. Is this the case?

"an actual resolver (e.g. that queries mainstream resolver such as google,)” is self-contradictory – an actual resolver wouldn't query "another mainstream resolver", but would directly query the authoritative servers. It's specifically the basic "router/browser/OS" caches that rely on querying such an another resolver... But yes, most routers only have a basic caching "proxy" and not a full "resolver" (aside from pfSense/OPNsense) – though it doesn't really.make a difference to the answer.

Thanks- that answers my question. Sorry for the slightly confusing technical language choices there in that comment, but you understood what I meant.

Though the OS facility is commonly called a "stub resolver" – i.e. it sends out DNS queries therefore it's still a specific kind of a "resolver", even if it relies on another (full) resolver to do the job. (This is separate from whether it caches. Linux for example has a stub resolver that doesn't cache, always querying a network server.)

In the classical case the browsers cache would be used first - although this cache (if it exists at all - not all browsers will have one) is short lived - typically 1 minute or so.

Thanks- this is what I guessed. Do you happen to have any sources to support this claim or just prior knowledge?

Mainly prior knowledge - some of my work requires modifying DNS/ local caches in preparation for migrating websites - but have a look at  Also google "web browser dns cache ttl" (TTL is key - its the caching timeout) for supporting evidence.
